# How do I implement IF in mulesoft

Tags: if-statement, mule

I want to make a decision in a Mulesoft flow, and have looked at the Choice Flow Control.  My problem, is that I want to do something if the condition is true, and nothing if it is false, something like:

```
if (condition == true)
   do some work
```

or, in probably incorrect xml:

```
<choice doc:name="call a subflow if the test is true">
    <when expression="#[flowVars.someVariable == True]">
        <flow-ref name="doSomething" doc:name="do another thing"/>
    </when>
</choice>
```

no else clause, and no default flow.  How is this implemented in a Mulesoft flow?
I could cheat, and throw a logging call into a default flow, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: outside of this, someone has suggested that I look at filters, but it seems to me that I would want to be using some sort of decision flow-control.  Or it could just be my bias of years of programming getting in the way of seeing the obvious solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple 'if' processor in Mule. Choice with a dummy otherwise route or filters are the way to go for now.

There is a good discussion on this here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6129. THis has further links to possible enhancements such as an if/detour router.

**Mule 4 UPDATE**

In mule 4, you can now define a choice router with no need for an `otherwise` route. And filters no longer exist

Comment: The simplest that I have found is to set variable:

<otherwise>
 <set-variable variableName="nullOp" value="nullOp" doc:name="nullOp" />
</otherwise>

Answer (score 4):

You can get close with an async or enricher scope and a filter.  It's not as elegant as a true `<if>` processor ([or a standalone `<when>`](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7136)), but you don't need a wasted `<logger>` to satisfy the `<otherwise>`.

Async method (when you don't need the payload afterwards):

```
<async>
    <expression-filter expression="#[payload == 'red']" />
    <logger category="com.box.integration.experiment" message="That's my favorite color!" level="INFO" />
</async>
```

Enricher method (when you do):

```
<enricher target="#[variable:colorName]">
    <processor-chain>
        <expression-filter expression="#[payload == 'red']" />
        <set-payload value="vermillion" />
    </processor-chain>
</enricher>
```

Comment: Apparently, I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer Ryan, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a mule flow, when using a  message router without setting a Processor in the  section, and the MuleMessage does not match any of the  clauses, an exception is thrown. To achieve a conditional behavior currently mule requires to set a dummy processor on the otherwise clause. One usability improvement would be letting the message be processed by the remaining part of the flow if no  clause was matched and no  processor provided
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6129