# Mulesoft choice router - no action needed on the default path - is there a Mulesoft placeholder component that doesn't squander resources?

Tags: oauth, mule, mulesoft

I have a subflow that ensures an OAuth access token is current.  The token value is saved in an object store that expires the entry shortly before it times out.  When expired, a new token value is retrieved and placed in the object store.

[image: Choice router with useless placeholder]

I didn't find any straightforward examples of a Mule v3 methodology to refresh a token that utilizes an object store, so here's the code, if anyone's interested.

```
<sub-flow name="get_token">
   <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="TokenStore" key="StatusToken" defaultValue-ref="#['expired']" targetProperty="StatusToken" doc:name="Get token from Object Store"/>
   <choice doc:name="Expired?">
      <when expression="#[flowVars.StatusToken == 'expired']">
         <set-payload value="#[{'grant_type':'refresh_token', 'refresh_token':'${RefreshToken}'}]" doc:name="Set payload for token refresh"/>
         <http:request config-ref="HTTP-Token" path="${tokenPath}" method="POST" doc:name="Get new token">
            <http:request-builder>
               <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            </http:request-builder>
         </http:request>
            <dw:transform-message doc:name="Write token to flowVar">
               <dw:set-variable variableName="StatusToken">
                  <![CDATA[
                     %dw 1.0
                     %output application/java
                     ---
                     payload.access_token
                  ]]>
               </dw:set-variable>
            </dw:transform-message>
         <objectstore:store config-ref="TokenStore" key="StatusToken" value-ref="#[flowVars.StatusToken]" doc:name="Put token to Object Store"/>
      </when>
      <otherwise>
         <set-variable variableName="Useless" value="#['']" doc:name="Useless placeholder"/>
      </otherwise>
   </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

The flow works well as designed, but here's my question.  A choice router checks to see if the token has expired.  There is no action required otherwise, and the flow errors out if the default path is empty.  What's the simplest element to minimize processing and any resource utilization on the default path?

Comment: AFAIK you can keep the default empty. I haven't checked in Mule3 recently but in Mule4 it can be left empty.  I bet you tried it but in the rest case you haven't its worth a try.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105709/how-do-i-implement-if-in-mulesoft/29113924#29113924

Answer (score 1):

Following Ryan Carter's comment, this could be marked as a duplicate, but not really.
Here's the link:

[How do I implement IF in mulesoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105709/how-do-i-implement-if-in-mulesoft/29113924#29113924)

### Summary

#### Mule 4:

The `<otherwise>` tag is not needed

#### Mule 3:

A component is needed. I tend to use `Logger` with the level of `TRACE`, since log4j2 is smart and won't substitute parameters if the level is set to `DEBUG` and higher. However, if you really need to debug a flow, it would be good to see that it got routed correctly.